# Sharepoint Power PI Connection Requiring Input Of Credentials

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerbi

I have an excel workbook with 8 Power BI queries to a Sharepoint site. The queries work, but every day I have to clear the permissions on the data source. I then have to reconnect by re entering credentials. Is there a way to remove this step? Ultimately I want to automate this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by file sitting on a server that was being accessed by various users. Solution was to move to a local machine. This allowed the credentials to be stored correctly.